# How to call my handler instead of ResetPerspectiveHandler when clicked on ResetPerspective?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

When I click on `ResetPerspective` in my RCP application, `execute()` method of `ResetPerspectiveHandler` is getting called and its a predefined handler.

I need to perform some task before so I created a handler which extends `ResetPerspectiveHandler`. So now the flow should be like when I click on `ResetPerspective` first my handler should get called from there `ResetPerspectiveHandler` will be called (`super.execute()`). 
How can I call my handler instead of `ResetPerspectiveHandler`?

Comment: `ResetPerspectiveHandler` is an **internal** class, you are violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by extending it. Anyway I don't know of a way to override the handler.

Comment: Note that you can use `IPerspectiveListener` to listen to perspective changes.